# Command for open terminal to a specified path

Tags: command-line, xdotool

I am using a tool which has an option to set up the command to open a custom terminal. I want to open a terminal to a specified folder (i.e - "/home/user/Desktop"). So far I have just been able to write the command to open a terminal.

`xdotool key ctrl+alt+t`

How can I open it to open terminal to a specified folder?

I am using ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be a better and more reliable solution to run the command to open a terminal session instead of pressing ctrl+alt+t via a command. If you are using the default gnome-terminal in Ubuntu 14.04 (Which you probably are if it opens with ctrl+alt+t), then you should try:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/your/path/here
```

That should open a terminal session in that directory without any input-related issues that come along with emulating key presses. Also keep in mind that not everyone has the ctrl+alt+t shortcut set up, they might have it disabled.

I hope this helped you!